# Lifnei Iver for a chinuch-age child

Tags: halacha, chinuch-education, lifnei-iver

Is there a prohibition of *lifnei iver* (causing or being an accessory to someone else's sinning) for a child who has reached the age of *chinuch* (education to *mitzvos*, the point at which he/she should be taught to keep *mitzvos*)?

For example, can an adult give food to a non-religious 10 year old who won't be making a blessing on it (precluding all exterior factors which could make this not technically *lifnei iver*)?

I am looking for explicitly sourced answers, not extrapolations based on some other detail or understanding of how *lifnei iver* works.

Comment: You're asking that since we have an obligation to acclimate him to Torah observance, and giving him food that he won't make a bracha on fails to enforce it, is it a violation of indirectly contributing to future transgressions? Since it certainly isn't a current transgression to qualify as a michshol...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky actually, according to the Steipler, it is, he just has a ptur oness.

Comment: because he's a child he is an oness?  I mean, I guess, yes, technically that's true, but then wouldn't EVERY transient ptur be considered an oness? I find that logic a bit hard to swallow.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know what you mean by "transient ptur"

Comment: I used that phrase to exclude people permanently pattur for other reasons. A woman isn't pattur oness, she's pattur gamur. A child will eventually grow up to become chayiv, so his ptur is transient. If the Steipler was referring SPECIFICALLY to a child as a ptur oness to the exclusion of other pturim, then it is even stranger and harder to understand. Do you have a link to his reasoning?

Comment: Isnt this basically the sugya of safin lei biyadayim?

Comment: IIRC - There is a rule that a father must not spank a child because of "lifnei iver". This would be an example of not applying this rule to a **ben chinuch**, no?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't have a link - it's in kehillos yaakov in Sukkah IIRC.  But I don't know what about it bothers you. Many transient peturim are onsim.  His point is just to say that that which ketanim are patur is not because the Torah was not mechayev them until gadlus but that they are onsim until then.  I think by other transient onsim this is obvious and it is a chiddush here.  He has a very good proof from a gemara in Sanhedrin.

Comment: @user6591 no, this is not a cheftza shel issur.

Comment: @DanF that halacha according to dina d'gemara is probably referring to a halachically adult child.

Comment: @YeZ It bothers me because being a kattan isn't like other transient peturim, especially because we typically group it with either cheresh/shoteh or nashim/avadim, none of which are transient in nature nor would they fall under the concept of oness, unless you're reinterpreting the meaning of it to be ridiculously broad. Other examples of onusim/oness don't provide room in their paradigm for a kotton stam. I'll see if I can look at it inside.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky why isn't shoteh transient in nature?  It is surely a p'tur of oness.  I don't know what else it would be.  Consider an עתים חלים.  While he is a shoteh, he is patur - what gzeiras hakasuv do you think he is included in?

Comment: Only the father is obligated in the *chinuch* of his children; other adults are only prohibited from giving him an *issur* (forbidden item) specifically (נותן לו איסור בידים). So the question should be whether it's considered giving him an issur, which I believe the answer would be not, since the food is not *assur*, he is merely not saying a *berachah* on it.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in [Moed Katan 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.17a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> דאמתא דבי רבי חזיתיה לההוא גברא דהוה מחי לבנו גדול אמרה ליהוי ההוא גברא בשמתא דקעבר משום ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול דתניא ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול במכה לבנו גדול
>
> The maidservant of Rebbi Yehuda HaNasi saw a man beating his mature son. She said: This man should be banned because he transgresses the prohibition of placing a stumbling block before the blind. For indeed we are taught in a Beraisa: You shall not place a stumbling block before the blind, this verse refers to a man who hits his mature son.

Thus, if a parent hits their child they are creating the potential for the child to strike back, which will result in that child violating an issur D'oraisa. [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.17a.13?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Moed_Katan.17a.13.1&lang2=bi) there notes that although the child may rebel and sin, the responsibility lies with the parent. Ultimately, if the parent were to exercise more control, the child will not learn the art of retaliation and will gain greater respect for their parent. However, it is important to note, how old we deem a “בנו גדול” – “mature son”? The [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 240:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.240.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings this scenario down in halacha and the Rema says that this refers to a son aged 22 or 24 years old.

**HOWEVER**, (I note your point in the comments above), the [Ritva](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.17a.13?lang=bi&p2=Ritva_on_Moed_Katan.17a.15&lang2=bi) goes one stage further. He notes that when the Gemara refers to a "בנו גדול" it is not necessarily a גדול, if a young child is of the disposition to respond in a similar fashion, then the issur extends to him as well. The only reason why the Gemara uses the term "gadol" there, is because it is more likely to happen with an older son.

> ונראי' דברים דלא גדול גדול ממש אלא הכל לפי טבעו שיש לחוש שיתרם כנגדו בדבור או במעשיו כי אפי' לא יהא בר מצוה אין ראוי להביאו לידי מכה או מקלל אביו שלא ישתדלנו בדברים ומשום דאורחא דמילתא דבגדול שכיח כי הוא נקט גדול

(Parenthetically, Rav Shlomo Wolbe zt"l adds (see ספר זריעה ובנין בחינוך, 'ענישה', עמוד כה) that in this present day, if one even hits a three-year-old, the likelihood is that they will hit you back!)